# MongoDB: Connection String Error when Upgrading Config Servers to Replica Set

Tags: mongodb

I'm following [these](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-config-servers-to-replica-set/) instructions to upgrade my Mongo config servers to a replica set. Everything seems to work initially, but then when connecting to a `Mongos` and running `sh.status`, I get the following error message and stack.

Of importance: "**Detected upgrade from mirrored (SCCC) config servers to replica set (CSRS) config servers.  setShardVersion was given: csReplSet/mongodb-config-1:27019 for the config server connection string, but has stored: mongodb-config-1:27019,mongodb-config-2:27019,mongodb-config-3:27019**

This causes the `PRIMARY` and one of the `SECONDARY` config servers to crash. I checked that all `mongos` have the right connection string and that all `mongod` and `mongos` are running the same version of MongoDB (3.2.11). I also tried firing up config servers from scratch (at the expense of losing data), but to no avail.

Any ideas?

```
2016-12-13T08:27:47.825+0000 I SHARDING [conn849] Detected upgrade from mirrored (SCCC) config servers to replica set (CSRS) config servers.  setShardVersion was given: csReplSet/mo\
ngodb-config-1:27019 for the config server connection string, but has stored: mongodb-config-1:27019,mongodb-config-2:27019,mongodb-config-3:27019
2016-12-13T08:27:47.825+0000 F -        [conn849] Invalid access at address: 0x108
2016-12-13T08:27:47.831+0000 F -        [conn849] Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault).

 0x132f902 0x132ea59 0x132edd8 0x7f288d434330 0x7f288d42e404 0x1140949 0xfa1480 0xbd2653 0xbd34d9 0xb2c1f0 0xce12f5 0x9be81c 0x12dc0c5 0x7f288d42c184 0x7f288d15937d
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"400000","o":"F2F902","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"400000","o":"F2EA59"},{"b":"400000","o":"F2EDD8"},{"b":"7F288D424000","o":"10330"},{"b":"7F288D4\
24000","o":"A404","s":"pthread_mutex_lock"},{"b":"400000","o":"D40949","s":"_ZN5mongo24ForwardingCatalogManager37scheduleReplaceCatalogManagerIfNeededENS_14CatalogManager16ConfigSer\
verModeERKNS_16ConnectionStringE"},{"b":"400000","o":"BA1480"},{"b":"400000","o":"7D2653","s":"_ZN5mongo7Command3runEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_3rpc16RequestInterfaceEPNS3_21ReplyB\
uilderInterfaceE"},{"b":"400000","o":"7D34D9","s":"_ZN5mongo7Command11execCommandEPNS_16OperationContextEPS0_RKNS_3rpc16RequestInterfaceEPNS4_21ReplyBuilderInterfaceE"},{"b":"400000\
","o":"72C1F0","s":"_ZN5mongo11runCommandsEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_3rpc16RequestInterfaceEPNS2_21ReplyBuilderInterfaceE"},{"b":"400000","o":"8E12F5","s":"_ZN5mongo16assembleResp\
onseEPNS_16OperationContextERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE"},{"b":"400000","o":"5BE81C","s":"_ZN5mongo16MyMessageHandler7processERNS_7MessageEPNS_21AbstractMessag\
ingPortE"},{"b":"400000","o":"EDC0C5","s":"_ZN5mongo17PortMessageServer17handleIncomingMsgEPv"},{"b":"7F288D424000","o":"8184"},{"b":"7F288D05F000","o":"FA37D","s":"clone"}],"proces\
sInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.2.11", "gitVersion" : "009580ad490190ba33d1c6253ebd8d91808923e4", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.4.0-53-gener\
ic", "version" : "#74~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 03:43:31 UTC 2016", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "elfType" : 2, "b" : "400000", "buildId" : "55994D9F4E3C47C30959A86BC9F3\
3188CB6ADF21" }, { "b" : "7FFCEDF32000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "AA5EEB9DFDD3AABAC9F493EC883C381016A1C312" }, { "b" : "7F288E346000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1\
.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "15A6A69B862FAC0AA589921DB1B0DF8A673FEC81" }, { "b" : "7F288DF6A000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId"\
 : "607C4A6F3428B6F065D55691AFDC4E343786A8A5" }, { "b" : "7F288DD62000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E2A6DD5048A0A051FD61043BDB69D8CC681\
92AB7" }, { "b" : "7F288DB5E000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DA9B8C234D0FE9FD8CAAC8970A7EC1B6C8F6623F" }, { "b" : "7F288D858000", "path\
" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D144258E614900B255A31F3FD2283A878670D5BC" }, { "b" : "7F288D642000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1\
", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "36311B4457710AE5578C4BF00791DED7359DBB92" }, { "b" : "7F288D424000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "31E\
9F21AE8C10396171F1E13DA15780986FA696C" }, { "b" : "7F288D05F000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "CF699A15CAAE64F50311FC4655B86DC39A479789" }\
, { "b" : "7F288E5A5000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D0F537904076D73F29E4A37341F8A449E2EF6CD0" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x32) [0x132f902]
 mongod(+0xF2EA59) [0x132ea59]
 mongod(+0xF2EDD8) [0x132edd8]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x10330) [0x7f288d434330]
 libpthread.so.0(pthread_mutex_lock+0x4) [0x7f288d42e404]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo24ForwardingCatalogManager37scheduleReplaceCatalogManagerIfNeededENS_14CatalogManager16ConfigServerModeERKNS_16ConnectionStringE+0x39) [0x1140949]
 mongod(+0xBA1480) [0xfa1480]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo7Command3runEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_3rpc16RequestInterfaceEPNS3_21ReplyBuilderInterfaceE+0x473) [0xbd2653]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo7Command11execCommandEPNS_16OperationContextEPS0_RKNS_3rpc16RequestInterfaceEPNS4_21ReplyBuilderInterfaceE+0x3F9) [0xbd34d9]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo11runCommandsEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_3rpc16RequestInterfaceEPNS2_21ReplyBuilderInterfaceE+0x1F0) [0xb2c1f0]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo16assembleResponseEPNS_16OperationContextERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE+0xB45) [0xce12f5]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo16MyMessageHandler7processERNS_7MessageEPNS_21AbstractMessagingPortE+0xEC) [0x9be81c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo17PortMessageServer17handleIncomingMsgEPv+0x325) [0x12dc0c5]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x8184) [0x7f288d42c184]
 libc.so.6(clone+0x6D) [0x7f288d15937d]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
2016-12-13T08:27:47.831+0000 F -        [conn849] /proc/self/maps:
00400000-02008000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2125                               /usr/bin/mongod
2016-12-13T08:27:47.831+0000 F -        [conn849] 02008000-020db000 rw-p 01c07000 08:01 2125                               /usr/bin/mongod
2016-12-13T08:27:47.831+0000 F -        [conn849] 020db000-0214b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.831+0000 F -        [conn849] 02885000-03486000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
2016-12-13T08:27:47.831+0000 F -        [conn849] 03486000-08972000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
2016-12-13T08:27:47.831+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f28689ba000-7f28689bb000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.831+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f28689bb000-7f2868abb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.831+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f2868abb000-7f2868abc000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.831+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f2868abc000-7f2868bbc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.831+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f2868bbc000-7f2868bbd000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.831+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f2868bbd000-7f2868cbd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.831+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f2868cbd000-7f2868cbe000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
.
.
.
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288c85e000-7f288c85f000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288c85f000-7f288d05f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288d05f000-7f288d219000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3079                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288d219000-7f288d419000 ---p 001ba000 08:01 3079                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288d419000-7f288d41d000 r--p 001ba000 08:01 3079                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288d41d000-7f288d41f000 rw-p 001be000 08:01 3079                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288d41f000-7f288d424000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288d424000-7f288d43d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3042                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288d43d000-7f288d63c000 ---p 00019000 08:01 3042                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288d63c000-7f288d63d000 r--p 00018000 08:01 3042                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288d63d000-7f288d63e000 rw-p 00019000 08:01 3042                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288d63e000-7f288d642000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288d642000-7f288d658000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3111                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288d658000-7f288d857000 ---p 00016000 08:01 3111                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288d857000-7f288d858000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 3111                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288d858000-7f288d95d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3084                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288d95d000-7f288db5c000 ---p 00105000 08:01 3084                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288db5c000-7f288db5d000 r--p 00104000 08:01 3084                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288db5d000-7f288db5e000 rw-p 00105000 08:01 3084                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288db5e000-7f288db61000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3076                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288db61000-7f288dd60000 ---p 00003000 08:01 3076                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288dd60000-7f288dd61000 r--p 00002000 08:01 3076                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288dd61000-7f288dd62000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 3076                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288dd62000-7f288dd69000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3002                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288dd69000-7f288df68000 ---p 00007000 08:01 3002                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288df68000-7f288df69000 r--p 00006000 08:01 3002                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288df69000-7f288df6a000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 3002                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288df6a000-7f288e11d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3012                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288e11d000-7f288e31c000 ---p 001b3000 08:01 3012                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288e31c000-7f288e337000 r--p 001b2000 08:01 3012                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288e337000-7f288e342000 rw-p 001cd000 08:01 3012                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288e342000-7f288e346000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288e346000-7f288e39b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3059                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288e39b000-7f288e59b000 ---p 00055000 08:01 3059                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288e59b000-7f288e59e000 r--p 00055000 08:01 3059                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288e59e000-7f288e5a5000 rw-p 00058000 08:01 3059                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288e5a5000-7f288e5c8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3010                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288e62d000-7f288e62f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288e62f000-7f288e7b8000 r--p 00000000 08:01 28741                      /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288e7be000-7f288e7c5000 r--s 00000000 08:01 29034                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288e7c5000-7f288e7c7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288e7c7000-7f288e7c8000 r--p 00022000 08:01 3010                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288e7c8000-7f288e7c9000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 3010                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7f288e7c9000-7f288e7ca000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7ffcede0e000-7ffcede2f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7ffcedf30000-7ffcedf32000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] 7ffcedf32000-7ffcedf34000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
2016-12-13T08:27:47.833+0000 F -        [conn849] ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that there were still some `mongos` instances using the old (mirrored) connection string. It seems that even `mongos` instances that are not up keep on pinging the config servers which cause the error and the fatal crash. Do `use config; db.mongos.find()` to find all your `mongos` instances and make sure they are all using the updated connection string without exception.